# equivalence relation on $V$ where $V$ is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $u,v \in V$, we define $u \equiv v \mod{W}$ if $u-v \in W$ where $W$ is a subspace of $V$

I'm a bit confused as to why this definition of the difference between two vectors is used. Could it equivalently have been the sum of two vectors is in $W$?

Why is the following statement true?

$[v]_W$ is a subspace of $V$ iff $v \in W$

Comment: What is the definition of "equivalence relation"?  Check that the clauses in that definition are satisfied in this case.  You will see that using $u+v$ will not work in (at least)  one of the things you must check.  For the second question, use the defintion of "subspace".

Comment: Please explain some more of your notation: is $W$ a subspace of $V$? Does $[v]_W$ mean the equivalence class of $v$? If so, $[v]_W$ is not a vector space, but an affine space.

Comment: Your post is kind of all over the place. You have asked two separate questions: (1) Why is the difference of vectors used to define equivalence mod $W$? (2) Why it is true that $[v]_W$ is a subspace of $W$ if and only if $v \in W$? And then you have given us your attempts at solving a still different and unstated question (3) Why is [something unspecified] closed under addition?. This is a situation where you ***really*** should follow our guidelines to [ask one question per post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#33671).

Comment: Oh, my bad. I haven't read it before. I will follow from now on!

Comment: @GEdgar thank you, that makes sense.

Comment: @LeeMosher I have changed the post. sorry

Comment: We use the difference because we are saying that two vectors are equivalent if they are in the same coset, i.e. $u-v\in W\implies u\in (W+v)$.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably $W$ is a subspace of $V$. The answer to your first question is it depends. If the scalar field has characteristic $2$, then of course $u - v = u + v$, so the two definitions coincide. If the field has characteristic other than $2$, then note $u + u = 2u \in W$ if and only if $u \in W$. So the relation defined by the sum would not even be reflexive unless $W = V$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I am not sure what characteristic 2 means. And yes, W is a subspace of V. I'll edit the question now.

Comment: "Characteristic $2$" is a property of the set of numbers your scalars come from (called a field). If you haven't heard of it, don't worry; just know it's a rare property and the notion of "characteristic" will come up in your studies when it's relevant. The numbers you're working with (presumably real or complex) are of characteristic $0$, for reference. (But essentially "characteristic $n$" means that
$$\underbrace{x+x+\cdots+x}_{\text{$n$ times}} = 0$$
for every $x$, except characteristic $0$ which is when this does not for any positive $n$.)